# Storing decimal precision in a variable

Tags: java, precision, decimalformat

Is there any way that I can store up to 6 decimal places in a double variable? For example, consider a double variable whose value is 1.0 but I want the value stored to be 1.000000

Background: I took an assessment test by mettl. I was asked to write a program to calculate mean, median and mode. The results should be stored in output variables of double type, namely output1, output2 and output3. Also, I was asked to store it with six decimal places. As I cannot use print statements there DecimalFormat is of no use.

Comment: What do you mean *stored*? In a database? In a file? As a string/text? As a number? In binary?

Comment: By stored I mean that when I print that variable it should display 1.000000
For instance, consider double variable d and System.out.println(d);
Should display 1.000000

Comment: Maybe use DecimalFormat before printing or @james large's answer. Both should work. BigDecimal stops allowing you to do normal operations, but instead you use the BigDecimal methods such as x.add(y). If you are going to use it, keep that in mind

Answer (score 7):

You misunderstand the nature of doubles.  There is no difference between 1.0 and 1.000000.  They are both the same number.

There *is* a difference between "1.0" and "1.000000":

```
String.format("%.1f", 1.0) //returns "1.0"

String.format("%.6f", 1.0) //returns "1.000000"
```

Additional Info:

Some people are telling you to use BigDecimal instead of double.  That may be the answer to your question, but it depends on what your question really is.  You said, you want to store "6 digits of precision".  A double can store around 16 digits of precision, but "digits of precision" is not the same thing as digits after the decimal point.

What are you *really* trying to accomplish?

Comment: These decimalformats can only print the decimals right? But I want to make the variable store six decimal places. Isnt that possible?

Comment: It isn't possible to make the variable store *less* than about 16 significant figures. That's what a `double` *is*.

Comment: Actually I took an assessment test by mettl. I was asked to write a program to calculate mean, median and mode. The results should be stored in output variable of double type namely output1, output2 and output3. Also I was asked to store it like this. I cannot use print statements.

Answer (score 2):

For a restricted range of values, a regular `double` has the required 6 digits precision after the period.

Are you looking to have exactly 6 digits of precision? (and not more) You may want to look at fixed-point arithmetics (there is libraries for it). Are you looking to have at least 6 digits after the dot, for arbitrarily large values? `BigDecimal` can do this.

Are you looking to represent `1.0` as `1.000000`? This is a display, not a maths issue. Use a string or rather, keep the number in one of the aforementioned representations and format accordingly..

Comment: Ya, I am looking to represent 1.0 as 1.000000. But I want to variable to store that many decimals.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Why? There is just no difference between 1.0 and 1.000000.

Comment: @Gumbo Yes there is no difference. But I am taking an exam and the question was like that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't normally recommend BigDecimal but it seems to be what you want. In particular you want a BigDecimal with a *scale* of 6. It easiest if you also set up a MathContext with precision of 6. I think you will need to manually set the scale at each step.

```
    BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal("1.0",mc).setScale(6); // preferred constructor using a string 
    BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal(3.0,mc).setScale(6);   // will work in this case as scale is set 
    BigDecimal bd3 = bd1.divide(bd2,mc).setScale(6);       // need to specify the context and scale for each operation
    BigDecimal bd4 = bd1.multiply(bd2,mc).setScale(6);     // need to specify the context for each operation
    System.out.println(bd1);
    System.out.println(bd2);
    System.out.println(bd3);
    System.out.println(bd4);
```

Giving 1.000000, 3.000000, 0.333333, 3.000000 as results.

Of course having 6 decimal places everywhere actually makes some sums worse if you do

```
    BigDecimal bd5 = bd3.multiply(bd2,mc).setScale(6);
```

you get 0.999999 as an answer, which is worse than if you have used doubles.

Answer (score 0):

If its about printing you can do:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out);

double x = 1.0;

out.printf("%,6f", 1.0);
```

This will print `1.000000`